# Recommended tasks for task scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2003, automation

Whats some tasks I can add to task scheduler to optimize the running of my servers?

I already have a weekly defrag of all my hard drives. 
A daily server reboot and a weekly disk cleanup and chkdsk.

Comment: File Server Resource Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use it (only) to clean up tmp and log files.

Answer (score 2):

There's no general rule, and the tasks you're running have a very high chance of creating much more troubles that they should theoretically solve.

I (and I'm quite sure this is not only me) strongly advise you against routinely defragmenting your disks, and even chkdsk really shouldn't be used unless you suspect file system damage. The daily reboot is just pointless: if you have performance problems (like memory leaks), you should solve *them* instead of rebooting the server. And if you don't have any, then why bother with the reboot?

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest you have a look at Microsoft Operations Framework 4.0
MS is starting to rekindle some respect from me by providing good clear advice through projects like this.... for free no less...

Have a look at this URL: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923724.aspx

You will find guides on suggested tasks and how often to perform them. From there you decide how to automate them...

I also agree with Massimo, no need to reboot your server so often... With Win2k/NT4 maybe once a month. 2003/2008 only reboot when you have problems. Chkdsk only if you have problems. Defrag once a week is fine in my mind.